# Creating RFID Enabled Application in C#

Tags: c#

I have a ACR122U-A9 RFID reader and some Mifare 1K cards. I want to develop a RFID enabled application in C#,but I dont know how to start developing. 
First I want to read Unique ID from tags, it is needs for associate's a member from a database.Secondly I want to read/write some data from/to tags.

I really stocked here. I read a tone of documentations I tried to work with SmartCard appi but I cant found anything about how to read that unique ID from tags.

Regards,
Lori.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to contact the manufacturer and find out what kind of API they provide.